# Some doubts regarding truth table for the function \$(cd+b'c+bd')(b+d)\$?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

$$(cd+b'c+bd')(b+d)$$

Expanding we have $$(cd+b'c+bd')(b+d)=bcd+bd'+cd+b'cd$$

Express each function as sum of Minterm and Product of Maxterm.

If you have n-variables then you will have $$2^n$$ products. Following n=3 we have 8 minterm. But my book suggest that there are 16 terms.

I need some clarification on this. Help please.

Another question is why don't we simplified the terms using Boolean Algebra like we normally do?

Comment: This is electrical forum you can ask this type of questions here math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Hazem Digital logic and boolean algebra are just fine here at EE.SE.

Comment: Perhaps they were assuming there was another variable "a", whose value is irrelevant?

Comment: It makes sense but the variable is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am working out the Digital Design by Morris.

Comment: Did you post the whole question from the book?

Comment: (b) of the question Sir. The whole question is for me to obtain truth table of the following functions and express each function is sum-of-minterms or product-of-maxterms.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you or validate what you have done? Its valid if n=4, yet you are hinting that should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variables are \$b\$, \$c\$, and \$d\$, then your eight minterms are:

$$\begin{align}
& bcd \\
& bcd' \\
& bc'd \\
& bc'd' \\
& b'cd \\
& b'cd' \\
& b'c'd \\
& b'c'd' \\
\end{align}$$

Your formula was:

$$bcd + bd′ + cd + b′cd$$

To express this in terms of minterms, you have to fill in the missing variables. Let's look at \$bd'\$. The \$c\$ is missing, which means it has no effect on \$bd'\$. So we can write this as:

$$bd' = bcd' + bc'd'$$

You could simplify the equation first:

$$bcd + bd' + cd + b'cd = bd' + cd$$

but if you need the minterms, you'll just have to expand it again.